# NextJS on-demand revalidation for server layout component

Tags: next.js

I have just started working on a new application using NextJS 13 and MongoDB.

This application has a navigation menu whose elements depend on a configuration object stored in the DB. As it is set now, the navigation menu is part of a server layout component that fetches the configuration object from the DB and then it displays it. Since I want this navigation menu to be configurable, I implemented an admin page where an admin user can change the configuration object for the navigation menu stored in the DB.

In order to update the navigation menu when the configuration object changes, I first set the `revalidate` variable. Then, I discovered the [on-demand revalidation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/revalidating#on-demand-revalidation) feature and I immediately tried the example (since I see it more ideal for my use case). However, it seems to work only for pages (specifying the routes). Since my layout component is used on every page, I should specify the routes of all the pages to revalidate the layout.

Thus, is there a way to use on-demand revalidation to revalidate a layout component in NextJS 13? If possible, I would like to avoid the automatic revalidation.

Answer (score 2):

I too was on the hunt for this answer. I was scratching my head for a long time until I found out that the revalidatePath function, takes a second parameter `type`.

This can either be `page` or `layout`. If you specify `layout`, it will:

> This will revalidate any URL that matches the provided layout file on the next page visit.

See docs here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath#revalidating-a-layout-path

In your case, if your layout is the root layout, you can just use:

```
revalidatePath('/', 'layout');
```

To revalidate the layout file in the route path. This will work for all pages that use that file.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes, I also found out about `revalidatePath` and it seems to work fine :)